# How to redirect stdout stderr in an ant script?

Tags: ant, stdout, cruisecontrol, stderr

I am triggering an ant script (via cruise control), and would like to be able to **dump the std out and std err** for a **particular ant target** to a plain **text file**.

Yes, I am aware that cruise control already does maintain an XML log file containing this information (among many other things), but for portability reasons, I need this to happen from the ant script itself.

Is this possible, and if so, how to do it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [recorder](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html) task may be able to do what you want:

```
<record name="log.txt" action="start"/>
...
<record name="log.txt" action="stop"/>
```

Beyond that, certain tasks (exec, java, etc) offer this functionality by themselves (usually by means of  `output` and `error` arguments)

Answer (score 10):

It's easy:

```
ant -logfile <logfile> <command>
```

And you can also say to ant shut up:

```
ant -q <command>
```

It worked fine to me.

Comment: That would work on the command line, I was looking for a solution that would work within an ant script. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<java classname="some.package.Class"
    fork="yes"
    output="stdouterr.txt">
    ...
</java>
```

`stdouterr.txt` will contain both stdout and stderr

```
<java classname="some.package.Class"
    fork="yes"
    output="stdout.txt"
    error="stderr.txt">
    ...
</java>
```

`stdout.txt` and `stderr.txt` will contain stdout and stderr respectively

From my experience, the record task tends to fail when the ant script is run on cruise control, due to file access permissions (if someone can tell me how to fix that I'll be a happy man).

HTH

Comment: You just need to make sure that the user CC runs as has write permissions to the file - it most certainly does work. The advantage "record" has is that it will capture output of **any** task, not just the ones that support that internally.