# Ant places stacktraces in standard output

Tags: java, logging, ant, stderr

I am using Ant, together with tasks I have created myself.
When those custom ant tasks fail, their output is redirected to stdout.

I want them to be redirected to stderr.

A simple full generic Ant example is :

```
<project name="test" default="init" basedir=".">

    <!-- Initialise project parameters -->
    <target name="init">
          <echo message="This is error message." level="error" />
    </target>
</project>
```

which properly outputs "This is error message" to stderr as can be seen :

```
Buildfile: /home/jll/Downloads/loggingerror.xml

init:
     [echo] Something wrong here.
     **[echo] This is error message.**

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

The line in bold shows as red in Eclipse, which indicates it is in the error standard output.

Now when I run my custom ant file :

```
<project name="test2" default="init" basedir=".">
    <taskdef resource="resource/customtasks.properties" />
    <target name="init" >

        <log
            scriptid="S4"
            message="Initialising Project Parameters."
            min="0"
            max="5"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Running this is expected to fail with a NullPointerException.

The output indeed shows as expected :

```
Trying to override old definition of task import

init:
      [log] java.lang.NullPointerException
      .......
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
      [log]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      [log]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      [log]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      [log]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
      [log]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

But in this case, everything goes to stdout. Why?

My Java code to throw exceptions in my custom tasks is really simple :

```
@Override
public void execute() throws BuildException {
    try {
        stuff....
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BuildException(e);
    }
}
```

I have also been trying to fiddle with  **e.printStackTrace()** and **logger.error("message", e)** in my java code, without success so far. The behavior stays the same (everything sent to stdout) even though the errors to show.

What would be a way to see my stacktraces showing up, or at least some kind of errors message in stderr?

Thanks

Comment: Hi jlengrand, do you get any solution for this? I am also stuck in the same problem..please suggest, if you find out any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the same code as in Echo task

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Task;
import org.apache.tools.ant.util.ResourceUtils;
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.LogOutputResource;
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.StringResource;


public class MyLogTask extends Task {
    private String msg;

    public void execute() throws BuildException {
        try {
            ResourceUtils.copyResource(new StringResource(msg), new LogOutputResource(this, Project.MSG_ERR),
                                  null, null, false, false, true, null, null, getProject(), true);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new BuildException(ioe, getLocation());
        }
    }

    public void setMessage(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

Then the message goes to `stderr`

```
<project default="main">

    <taskdef name="mylog" classname="MyLogTask"/>

    <target name="main">
        <echo message="ERROR" level="error" />
        <mylog message="hello"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Here is the test:

```
/cygdrive/c/temp/ant>ant 
Buildfile: c:\temp\ant\build.xml

main:
     [echo] ERROR
    [mylog] hello

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
/cygdrive/c/temp/ant>ant 2>err
Buildfile: c:\temp\ant\build.xml

main:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
/cygdrive/c/temp/ant>
```

Comment: Hum, what's really interesting here is that my message doesn't show at all in the stack. It just isn't there if I use this method :S

Comment: If you use MyLogTask does it display the message?

Comment: Yes. I think it might come from my logger configuration. But I am in pain to find what exactly

Comment: Ok, so now I get why. My task is calling other java classes. The NullPointerException that I meet happens in classes level deeper than my task, and they handle the error themselves (and do a e.prinstacktrace). So my Ant task never catches the exception. How is it that the errors of those inner classes appear in stdout?

Comment: Well, if they call printstacktrace then it goes to stdout. You may change your design so that it's your main task who handles all exceptions

Comment: You are right. If I throw an Exception at higher level, everything works as expected. Is there not way to avoid inner levels stacktraces to be redirected?

Comment: Not that I know. Even if I do System.err.println() it goes to stdout

Answer (score 2):

It's don't think it's possible.

The closest solution if you don't have too many classes is to redirect the output for each class to a file (stderr) by doing something similar to what was described 
[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719201/how-to-redirect-stdout-stderr-in-an-ant-script)

However they also wanted to redirect stdout, but you can try this:

`<java classname="some.package.Class"
    output="stderr.txt">
    ...
</java>`

However this isn't really directing it to stderr, but it's close.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why are you saying this is not possible under ant? I know that the echo task achieves this, so it must be possible, isnt it?

Comment: Did you try  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607536/ant-exec-redirecting-standard-out-but-not-standard-error ? Sorry, your problem is harder than I first realized.

Comment: My first example sows that echo indeed does output to stderr without problem. I have looked at the source code of the task, without seeing exactly enables it. I have also tried to mimic the behaviour, without success so far.